# How to display hyperlinks in Echo Alexa cards

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

How do I display a hyperlink in an Echo Alexa card, i.e. the card that is displayed in the Alexa app after I talk to Echo? I understand its included in the response returned by the lambda function, but cannot find any documentation other than
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/providing-home-cards-for-the-amazon-alexa-app
https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/handling-requests-sent-by-alexa

neither of which discuss hyperlinks. When I try something such as `google.com, the entire ahref is outputted as regular text.

Asking Alexa for restaurant recommendations displays nicely formatted Yelp data, along with links to a map and/or the Yelp page itself.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot do this with the features currently presented in the Alexa Skills Kit. It has been a frequently requested feature. Amazon shot down an entire line of business I had planned for the Alexa specifically because they decided the Terms and Conditions of a third party service I was using required a "live link" to be presented, and they could not do this.

There is no question that *The Echo* can do this. As you noted, they do it all the time. But it is not a feature they have opened up to *Alexa* and 3rd party skills.