# How to embed 'read-more' like url in Standard Card response of Alexa

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have seen few apps which are able to embed links in the response of Standard card in Alexa.
for eg :: see the skill : https://www.amazon.co.uk/Guardian-News-Media-The-US/dp/B01N5HQRUC

They are able to show the links in the standard card response. [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbyrJ.jpg)

The documentation of the Alexa skills does not say anything about urls in the card response.

Comment: oh! really i thought it was not possible. See the so post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780665/how-to-display-hyperlinks-in-echo-alexa-cards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is a special skill called Flash Briefing skill. Though feed skill is still rendering as standard card, Amazon has not made embedding a link in the card response in custom skill available to public.

check the documentation: [alexa documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/understanding-the-different-types-of-skills)

[image: alexa console for configuring the feed-skill]

See this [link](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/flash-briefing-skill-api-feed-reference#feed-format-details). In the table there is something called **display Url** which will be rendered as the **read more** link in the card.

Answer (score 0):

That's not actually a "Standard Card" as you may understand it in the ASK sense - it's the text display of a Flash Briefing. Flash Briefing skills have always allowed for a "Read More" link. There's still no way to do it via custom skills, though.